# Replace multiple instance of word between identifier in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to replace every word between `%%` with a single word. Till now I tried this:

```
var string = "You chose %story% at %price%";

var rep = string.replace(/\%(.*)\%/g, "test");

console.log(rep);
```

but the result of `rep` is actually

```
"You chose test"
```

while I want

```
"You chose test at test"
```

How can I achieve this? I though about implementing a recursive function but it sound pretty slow especially with multiple words

Comment: Use non-greedy : `/%.*?%/g` or `/%[^%]*%/g`

Answer (score 0):

Try the snippet below, just put a lazy quantifier `?` after `*`, so that it will not take more than one occurrence

```js
var string = "You chose %story% at %price%";

var rep = string.replace(/%(.*?)%/g, "test");

console.log(rep);
```

Comment: the escape `%` was used by the OP